# jQuery close menu auto closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a mobile menu and would like when the user clicks on the document, not the menu to close the menu if its open.
Problem is that when the first click is fired to open the mobile it automatically closes. I'm struggling to get this bit to work.

The code recognises the click so the window is detecting the right action. I'm just missing one final step I think.

Code is:

```
$('.mobile-menu-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.mobile-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
// close on off click
$(window).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($('.mobile-menu').css("display") == 'block') {
        $('.mobile-menu').slideToggle();
        console.log('click');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: add `e.stopPropagation();` to the menu click handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation. When you click on '.mobile-menu', you open it or close it, when you click somewhere else you only close it.

```
$(window).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('mobile-menu-button')) {
      $('.mobile-menu').slideToggle('slow');
    } else {
      $('.mobile-menu').css('display') === 'block' && $('.mobile-menu').slideUp();
    }
});
```

a basic example on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6e7atrmn/2/

Comment: updated, it was some details, you shohld get the ideas form stackoverflow not the code

Comment: doesn't work, does the same thing that my code previously does. Slides down then immediately slides up.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but couldn't make the edit to it as it was shorter than 6 chars. It still doesn't work.

Comment: please check the fiddle that I post it, there is a working example of my proposal. It works.